# Grub halts on menu until enter is pressed

Tags: boot, grub2, uefi, raid

I have installed an Ubuntu server and it stops on the Grub Menu until <kbd>ENTER</kbd> is pressed without timing out and using the default entry.

At first I thought that the problem was due to a reboot after a power outage, so I set `GRUB_RECORDFAIL_TIMEOUT` and ran `update-grub`. But it didn't work.

I stops at the Grub Menu even when I restart the machine or when I stop it and starts it again.

When in menu I go into grub console (press <kbd>C</kbd>) and send the command `normal` it responses grub normal and the timeout works properly.

My configuration is:

```
 - Ubuntu         14.04.1 LTS 
 - grub-common    2.02~beta2-9ubuntu1 
 - grub2-common   2.02~beta2-9ubuntu1

4 disk on software raid 

 - md0 : active raid1 - /boot 
 - md1 : active raid10 - /
 - /dev/sdc1  - /boot/efi     (Efi partiiton)
```

EDIT: My /etc/default/grub is here: http://paste.ubuntu.com/10569187/

Comment: Post the uncomment settings in `/etc/default/grub`.

Comment: Could you please post your `/etc/default/grub` to http://paste.ubuntu.com and report back the linkt you're provided with, please...

Comment: /etc/default/grub
http://paste.ubuntu.com/10569187/

Comment: Unclear voters - note edit.

Answer (score 0):

There appear to be some missing (") quotation marks in your /etc/default/grub. Here's a comparison of the same section of **mine which works flawlessly**.

```
GRUB_DEFAULT="0"
#GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT="0"
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET="true"
GRUB_TIMEOUT="10"
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR="`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
```

**and yours which doesn't**

```
GRUB_DEFAULT=0
#GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true
GRUB_TIMEOUT=3
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=""
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
```